# How to Configure Always Encrypted using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, always-encrypted

I just want to ask if there is a way to configure always encrypted columns using power shell? like for example i want to encrypt a column in a table with deterministic using powershell codes?

Comment: Have you read the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-using-powershell?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: @HandyD You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Always Encrypted using PowerShell. This is documented in Microsoft's [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/configure-always-encrypted-using-powershell?view=sql-server-2017) page.